# How to configure 'readline' such that GNU/Octave's 'input' command can browse its history

Tags: readline, octave

In this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/octave --line-editing

a = input("command: ", "s");
a = input("command: ", "s");
```

during the second input, if you press the up arrow, it should show the command entered in the first input. At this point, Octave 4.0.0, after a fresh installation, does not show it. After much reading, I came to the conclusion that it's a `readline` thing, but can't figure out how to make it work.How to configure 'readline' such that GNU/Octave's 'input' command can browse its history